# Vuetify: How can I properly limit the max width of container on large screen sizes?

Tags: javascript, css, layout, flexbox, vuetify.js

My vuetify layout is based on flex:

```
<v-app>
  <v-navigation-drawer app clipped right permanent>...</v-navigation-drawer>
  <v-app-bar app clipped-right>...</v-app-bar>
  <v-main>
    <v-flex class="flex-column fill-height pa-4">
      ...
    </v-flex>
  </v-main>
</v-app>
```

This layout is good, but on large screen size it fits the whole width. I want to limit the width at 1200px. But if I set "max-width: 1200px" on any of `v-flex`, `v-main`, or even `v-app`, I get the container at the left side of screen, and the navigation drawer at the right side of screen. And the rest of whitespace is located between them.

What I want to get: summary width of container and navigation drawer must be = 1200px, they must be centered at the screen, and drawer should be pinned to the right side of container. On large screen sizes spacers should appear from left and right sides. Something like this:

```
[ . . . . . . . top bar . . . . . . . . ]
[space][....container....][drawer][space]
```

On smaller sizes container and drawer should fit the whole screen width.
Is it possible?

UPD: To be clear. Above is what I want to get on wide screen. On narrow screen I want to get:

```
[ . . . . top bar . . . . ]
[....container....][drawer]
```

What I get now at wide screen:

```
[ . . . . . . . top bar . . . . . . . . ]
[....container....][...space....][drawer]
```

Comment: use `v-spacer`?

Comment: where to use it?

Comment: where you have [space]? What should the  layout be on narrow screens?

Comment: I wrote: On smaller sizes container and drawer should fit the whole screen width. How to bind a drawer to the right side of the container?

Comment: so, use v-spacer wher eyou have [space] - did you try that?

Comment: No, I didn't. I have no idea where I should put it, because the drawer is not a child of v-main in layout and it does not come right after the container. So there is no "between" point in layout. Where should I put it? After </v-navigation-drawer>, </v-flex> or </v-main>?

Comment: oh, sorry, I didn't read that markup ... so where is `drawer` relative to the bit of markup you've shown. Edit: oh, vuetify - I see the issue now, sorry for the comment noise

Answer (score 2):

Instead of targeting vuetify-generated classes, you can put the navigation drawer inside the container, then add `position: relative` style to the container. Remove the `app` attribute to the drawer and replace it with `absolute` instead.

```html
<v-app>
  <v-main>
    <v-app-bar app clipped-right>Toolbar</v-app-bar>
    <v-container style="max-width: 1200px; position: relative;" class="d-flex pa-0">
      <div class="flex-column fill-height pa-4 flex-grow-1">Content</div>
      <v-navigation-drawer absolute clipped right permanent>Drawer</v-navigation-drawer>
    </v-container>
  </v-main>
</v-app>
```

```css
.main-container {
  position: relative !important;
  max-width: 1200px !important;
}
```

[image]

Here's a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-dew-isd4c?file=/src/App.vue):

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following css. This solution is not the most elegant, but will use it since I have no other ones. You should replace '1000px' with desirable max width for your container and '30px' with the sum of padding (or try experimental).

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .v-application {
        max-width: calc(1000px - 30px);
        margin-left: calc((100vw - 1000px) / 2);
    }

    .v-navigation-drawer--right {
        right: calc((100vw - 1000px) / 2);
    }
}
```